# What am I doing wrong with my extension?

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, extension

I have two salesforce custom objects, service case and customer. I am trying to make a page that displays data from both objects. I used service case as a standard controller and get no problems. I have created two extensions that I am trying out for the purpose of trying to get customer data on the page titled ServiceCaseTest.

Here is the code for ServiceCaseTest:

```
<apex:page standardController="Service_Case__c" extensions="CustomerExt">
    <apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock title="Service Case Summary">

    <apex:pageBlockSection title="Service Case Stuff"  columns="2">
          <apex:outputField value="{!Service_Case__c.Name}"/>
          <apex:outputField value="{!Service_Case__c.LGFProduct__c}"/>
    </apex:pageBlockSection>

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Payment" columns="2" rendered="{!if(Service_Case__c.Out_of_Warranty__c, true, false)}">
          <apex:outputField value="{!Service_Case__c.Payment__c}"/>
            <apex:inlineEditSupport disabled="false"/>
          <apex:outputField value="{!Service_Case__c.Received_Payment__c }"/>
            <apex:inlineEditSupport disabled="false"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>
        <apex:pageBlockButtons >
            <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
        </apex:pageBlockButtons>
</apex:pageBlock>
<!--<apex:pageBlock title = "Customer information">
    <apex:pageBlockSection title=" Customer Stuff"  columns="2">
          <apex:outputField value="{!Records.Name}"/> //with the second example I do use cust instead of records
          <apex:outputField value="{!Records.Country__c}"/> 
    </apex:pageBlockSection>
</apex:pageBlock> -->
</apex:form>
```

The commented out part gives me an error. When I do include the commented out part, I get the error: "Could not resolve the entity from  value binding '{!Records.Name}'.   can only be used with SObjects, or objects that are Visualforce field component resolvable."

The extension I have currently tried it with is:

```
public class CustomerExt{ 
public Customer__c customer {get;set;}
public CustomerExt(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) 
    {
        this.customer = (Customer__c)stdController.getRecord();
    }
List<Customer__c > SC = [SELECT CreatedById, CreatedDate, LastModifiedById, 
                       LastModifiedDate 
                       FROM Customer__c ];
public List<Customer__c> Records {get; set;} 
public CustomerExt(){ 
Records = 
[select Name,Id, City__c, Country__c, e_mail__c, Phone_Number__c, Service_Case_Operator__c, 
 State__c, Street__c, Zip_Postal_Code__c FROM Customer__c ]; 
} 
}
```

I also tried with a different extension and get another error. Attempt # 2

```
public with sharing class MyExtClass {
  private ApexPages.StandardController ctrl;
  public Customer__c  cust {get;set;}
  public MyExtClass(ApexPages.StandardController controllerParam){
      ctrl = controllerParam;
      cust = (Customer__c ) ctrl.getRecord();
  }
  public PageReference customsave(){
    //here I override my standard save functionality before I return the save call.
    return ctrl.save();
  }
}
```

I get no error when I change {!records.Name} to {!cust.Name} but instead when I preview this message pops up.

[image]
Why can't I get data from customer_c data to display on the ServiceCaseTest VF page.

edit:

I tried to change it to a pageBlock table. I am still receiving an error.

PageBlock table attempt:

```
<apex:page standardController="Service_Case__c" extensions="CustomerExt">
    <apex:form >
  <apex:pageBlock title="Service Case Summary">

        <apex:pageBlockSection title="Service Case Stuff"  columns="2">
              <apex:outputField value="{!Service_Case__c.Name}"/>
              <apex:outputField value="{!Service_Case__c.LGFProduct__c}"/>
        </apex:pageBlockSection>

            <apex:pageBlockSection title="Payment" columns="2" rendered="{!if(Service_Case__c.Out_of_Warranty__c, true, false)}">
              <apex:outputField value="{!Service_Case__c.Payment__c}"/>
                <apex:inlineEditSupport disabled="false"/>
              <apex:outputField value="{!Service_Case__c.Received_Payment__c }"/>
                <apex:inlineEditSupport disabled="false"/>
            </apex:pageBlockSection>
            <apex:pageBlockButtons >
                <apex:commandButton action="{!save}" value="Save"/>
            </apex:pageBlockButtons>

    <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Records}" var="Record"> 
            <apex:column > 
                <apex:facet name="header">Account Name</apex:facet> 
                <apex:outputLink value="/{!Record.Id}" id="theLink">{!Record.Name}</apex:outputLink> 
            </apex:column>
        </apex:pageBlockTable> 
        </apex:pageBlock>
    </apex:form>
</apex:page>
```

Changing it to a table gives no more error in the developer console but when previewed, the same error as above is still given.

Comment: Records is a list, but you trying to display it as a single line. Wrap it with apex:pageBlockTable

Comment: If I change the query to 1 would I work? Or would I still need pageBlockTable?

Comment: how many records do you want to see?

Comment: Actually I see what I am doing wrong. I only want to see one. It should be the customer that is related to the service case. There is a look-up relationship between them while now I am querying all customers. How would I make it so that my controller will query the record that is related to the service case?

Comment: you are using standard controller Service_Case__c, but you're initializing its with Customer__c object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Following example with ititiate extension with Service_Case__c Record and get one customer

```
public class CustomerExt { 
    public Service_Case__c service {get;set;}
    private list <Customer__c> customers;

    public CustomerExt(ApexPages.StandardController stdController) {
        this.service = (Service_Case__c)stdController.getRecord();

        customers = [select Name,Id, City__c, Country__c, e_mail__c, 
            Phone_Number__c, Service_Case_Operator__c, State__c, Street__c, 
            Zip_Postal_Code__c 
            FROM Customer__c where Service_Case__c = :service.id limit 1];

    }

    public Customer__c getCustomer() {
        if (!customers.isEmpty())
            return customers[0];
        else 
            return null;
    }
}
```

Now you should be able to use apex:outputfield:

```
<apex:pageBlockSection title=" Customer Stuff"  columns="2" rendered = "{!Customer != null}">
      <apex:outputField value="{!Customer.Name}"/> 
      <apex:outputField value="{!Customer.Country__c}"/> 
</apex:pageBlockSection>
```